# how to read the "system.web.extentions" using the c# in mvc applications

Tags: c#

I am having the webconfig settings like the below.

```
 <system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

I need to read the "maxJsonLength" from the above code snippet using the C#. For this i have tried by using the,

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

but can get the value of the appsettings and connectionstring value.

Answer (score 0):

`MaxJsonLength` is a public property on `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`, which will return an Int containing the size.
Do notice that this is only available on **instances** of this class, so the easiest way to access it would be `(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).MaxJsonLength`